# Alter existing foreign constraint to new table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

In my DB, I've a table:

```
USER
----
Id      Number
Name    Varchar
SSN     Number
```

For some reason we wanted to alter `SSN` to `Varchar`. Since it was not empty, so we created new table instead of altering the existing one:

```
USER2
-----
Id      Number
Name    Varchar
SSN     Varchar
```

Copied all the data from `USER` to `USER2`.

Then renamed original `USER` to `USER_BACKUP`.

Renamed `USER2` to `USER`.

I know it was a bad approach but unfortunately it's done & in use.

As of today new `USER` table is ahead of `USER_BACKUP` as some data has now been added & deleted from it.

Now there are 2 existing table `ADDRESS` and `USER_ADDRESS`.

`USER_ADDRESS` stores relational data between `USER` & `ADDRESS` using *User's Id*(Foreign_Key) & *Address's Id*(Foreign_Key).

```
USER_ADDRESS
------------
Id          Number
User_id     Number
Address_Id  Number
```

But since original USER has been renamed, the foreign constraint has also been renamed and does not point to new `USER`, but it points to `USER_BACKUP`, which is not I wanted.

Data in `USER_BACKUP` is irrelevant to me now.

What steps should I follow to point `USER_ADDRESS` to new `USER` table, without affecting the data in both tables.

Please suggest.

P.S. - We are using Oracle 18C.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new constraint and drop the old constraint.

```sql
ALTER TABLE user_address ADD CONSTRAINT user_address__id__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "USER" ( id );
ALTER TABLE user_address DROP CONSTRAINT name_of_previous_fk_to_user_backup;
```

If the data in the two tables is still similar enough then it will work.

If you have deleted items from the new `USER` table that are still in `USER_BACKUP` and referenced from the `USER_ADDRESS` table then it will fail and you will need to reconcile the differences between the tables.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1b265c0d4c625fc63fc24c485afc8665)*